# Как вам это предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

**Диалог**

– Как вам это предложение: «Еще неизвестно, что произойдет».

– Вроде бы нормальное…

– Вот и все так говорят...Но дело в том, что оно в некотором роде особенное, других таких нет. В художественной литературе такого предложения не встретишь. Вероятно, писатели чувствуют в нем что-то некорректное...

А что там некорректного? Или это все-таки нормальное предложение?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141445/discussion-on-question-by-sharon----).

Comment: А если так? *Ещё неизвестно, что должно произойти.* Вроде бы устраняется.

Comment: Ну, это если только в небесную канцелярию обратиться.

Comment: Не понял. С "должно" уже не 100%, а высокая вероятность.

Comment: Должно произойти!  Да это, как я думаю,  написано только в Высших сферах, да и то в виде  плана на 2023 год.   Январь. Экстренное совещание на тему: Что нам с этими землянами делать?!

Comment: Нет, так часто говорят. *Должно было быть/произойти это, а произошло иначе.* То, что должен, не значит, что сделает.

Comment: Ладно, вас не убедишь.  Но партия все равно за мной, потому что в Нацкорпусе такого предложения нет (с такой грамматикой и лексикой). Или ищите, ага?

Comment: Дело в другом. Даже три подряд идущих слова в Нацкорпусе сложно найти, не говоря уже о четырёх. "В Нацкорпусе не могу найти" — это не аргумент, если речь не о двух словах или выражении. Что нашлось: https://www.google.com/search?q="известно,+что+произойдет"&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim4u_orov8AhXyEGIAHWPRCw0Q_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1366&bih=613&dpr=1

Comment: Я там целое исследование провела, вот и вы займитесь.  А в Гугле все не то, да и наречия "еще" нет. Нацкорпус - это национальная литература, а там переводы.

Comment: Имею в виду, что там есть "известно", а вы говорите: *Другими словами, в настоящем времени нет такого момента, когда мы «будем УЖЕ точно знать», что произойдет в будущем.* Но никто не говорит, что точно, это всё ориентировочно.

Comment: Единственное, что я там вижу некорректного, — это отсутствие вопросительного знака.